# V-for Loop not displaying data when I Query NewsAPI using Vuex and Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vuex

I started this project recently in Nuxt JS, all I wanted to do is get data from NewsAPI.org using Axios and Vuex which I did, showing the code below.

**news.js**

```
const endPoint = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us"

const state = {
  news: [],
  filteredNews: [],
};


const getters = {};


const mutations = {
  SET_NEWS(state, news) {
    state.news = news
  },
};

const actions = {
  // The News list API 
  async newsList({
    commit
  }) {
    try {
      const response = await this.$axios.$get(endPoint, config)
      const news = response.articles
      commit('SET_NEWS', news)
      console.log(news)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  },
};


export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
}
```

It worked fine and I was able to get data in my console finally, only to iterate through the data in my `news.vue` component, I get-

**news.vue**

```
<template>
 <section class="text-gray-600 bg-gray-50 font-body">
   <div  class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto" >
     <div class="grid grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-12"  >
       <div  class=""  v-for="article in news">
         <div  class="h-full border-2 border-gray-200 border-opacity-60 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
           <img class="lg:h-48 md:h-36 w-full object-cover object-center" src="https://dummyimage.com/722x402" alt="blog">
           <div class="p-6">
             <h2 class="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-800 mb-1">{{article}}</h2>
             <h1 class="title-font text-lg font-medium text-gray-900 mb-3">Shooting Stars</h1>
             <p class="leading-relaxed mb-3">Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.</p>
             <div class="flex items-center flex-wrap ">
               <a class="text-green-500 inline-flex items-center md:mb-2 lg:mb-0">
                 Learn More
                 <svg class="w-4 h-4 ml-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                   <path d="M5 12h14"></path>
                   <path d="M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
                 </svg>
               </a>
               <span class="text-gray-400 mr-3 inline-flex items-center lg:ml-auto md:ml-0 ml-auto leading-none text-sm pr-3 py-1 border-r-2 border-gray-200">
                 <svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                   <path d="M1 12s4-8 11-8 11 8 11 8-4 8-11 8-11-8-11-8z"></path>
                   <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3"></circle>
                 </svg>
                 1.2K
               </span>
               <span class="text-gray-400 inline-flex items-center leading-none text-sm">
                 <svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                   <path d="M21 11.5a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9 3.8 8.5 8.5 0 01-7.6 4.7 8.38 8.38 0 01-3.8-.9L3 21l1.9-5.7a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9-3.8 8.5 8.5 0 014.7-7.6 8.38 8.38 0 013.8-.9h.5a8.48 8.48 0 018 8v.5z"></path>
                 </svg>
                 6
               </span>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
 computed: {
   ...mapState(['news'])
 },
 created(){
   this.$store.dispatch('newsList')
 }
}
</script>
```

Finally when here is what I get when I try to add fields from the API.

[image]

The problem I face is when I try to display the variable from the object like {{article.content}}, the whole element just disappears.

Vue Data not displaying did not display from the API

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: When I try to use the variable like {{article.content}} the element just disappears.

Comment: It's because an article is an array, not an object. But it seems that the most important part of the code is missing, so it's hard to point to the exact problem in the code.

Comment: Can you add in the question that what is the data inside `news`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final answer. I had to loop an extra field in the array to access my data so it was v-for ="article in news.news"

```
<template>
 <section class="text-gray-600 bg-gray-50 font-body">
   <div  class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto" >
     <div class="grid grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-12"  >
       <div  class=""  v-for="article in news.news">
         <div  class="h-full border-2 border-gray-200 border-opacity-60 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
           <img class="lg:h-48 md:h-36 w-full object-cover object-center" src="https://dummyimage.com/722x402" alt="blog">
           <div class="p-6">
             <h2 class="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-800 mb-1">{{article}}</h2>
             <h1 class="title-font text-lg font-medium text-gray-900 mb-3">Shooting Stars</h1>
             <p class="leading-relaxed mb-3">Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.</p>
             <div class="flex items-center flex-wrap ">
               <a class="text-green-500 inline-flex items-center md:mb-2 lg:mb-0">
                 Learn More
                 <svg class="w-4 h-4 ml-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                   <path d="M5 12h14"></path>
                   <path d="M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
                 </svg>
               </a>
               <span class="text-gray-400 mr-3 inline-flex items-center lg:ml-auto md:ml-0 ml-auto leading-none text-sm pr-3 py-1 border-r-2 border-gray-200">
                 <svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                   <path d="M1 12s4-8 11-8 11 8 11 8-4 8-11 8-11-8-11-8z"></path>
                   <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3"></circle>
                 </svg>
                 1.2K
               </span>
               <span class="text-gray-400 inline-flex items-center leading-none text-sm">
                 <svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                   <path d="M21 11.5a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9 3.8 8.5 8.5 0 01-7.6 4.7 8.38 8.38 0 01-3.8-.9L3 21l1.9-5.7a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9-3.8 8.5 8.5 0 014.7-7.6 8.38 8.38 0 013.8-.9h.5a8.48 8.48 0 018 8v.5z"></path>
                 </svg>
                 6
               </span>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
 computed: {
   ...mapState(['news'])
 },
 created(){
   this.$store.dispatch('newsList')
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Which is correct right ?
article in itself is an object ( which in your case looks like an array however ).
you are trying to render article as a whole,
instead try to render one property inside article object.

for e.g -   instead of rendering {{article}}  try {{article.author}} or {{article.title}}

Comment: Vue Data not displaying when I try to access it via a variable like {{article.author}}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).